# PROLOG. Помогите решить задачу

Tags: логика, prolog, логические-выражения

Есть задача:

> "Расстановка мебели". Площадь разделена на шесть квадратов, пять из них заняты мебелью, шестой - свободен. Переставить мебель так, чтобы шкаф и кресло поменялись местами, при этом никакие два предмета не могут стоять на одном квадрате.

Как ее решить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вас интересует алгоритм или код?

Comment: Лучше код, но можно и алгоритм

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков не совсем понял, можете более понятным языком

Comment: Простите, не та ссылка... 
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Игра_в_15#Использование_пятнашек_в_информатике

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков вилите ли, я не совсем понял алгоритм из википедии... Спасибо, конечно, но не могли бы вы объяснить простым языком (как чайнику)

Comment: [Пример для пятнашек](https://github.com/diegodelemos/15-puzzle-prolog/blob/master/15-puzzle-Astar.pl) - в твоем случае вместо 4х4 нужно оставить 2х3

Comment: @Grundy в этом алгоритме нет зависимости от расположения свободной ячейки? похоже, что там она в правом нижнем углу

Comment: это конечное положение пустой клетки. просто адаптируй задачу пятнашек к себе: у тебя есть начальное положение. конченое и пустая клетка - как и в пятнашках

Comment: спасибо!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение задачи (неоптимальное):

```
    cell(1,1, stol). cell(1,2, stul1). cell(1,3, shkaf).

    cell(2,1, stul2). cell(2,2, 'EMPTY'). cell(2,3, chair).

    ic :- cell(X,Y, ITEM1), cell(X,Y, ITEM2), ITEM1 = ITEM2, !, fail; true. 

    move:-
      cell(X,Y, 'EMPTY'),
      cell(X1,Y1, ITEM1),
      cell(X2,Y2, ITEM2),
      retract(cell(X1,Y1, ITEM1)),
      assertz(cell(X,Y, ITEM1)),
      retract(cell(X2,Y2, ITEM2)),
      assertz(cell(X1,Y1, ITEM2)),
      retract(cell(X,Y, 'EMPTY')),
      assertz(cell(X2,Y2, 'EMPTY')),
      ic,
      fail; final_state.

    final_state :-
      cell(1,3, chair),
      cell(2,3, shkaf).
```